# How to calculate actual road distance on mkmapview?

Tags: ios, google-maps, mkmapview

I have calculated distance between 2 points(latitude and longitude). I used **distanceFromLocation:** but this gives me aerial distance. I have drawn **MKPolyline**
on **MKMapview** showing road route. Now the problem is that, how can i get the actual road distance without using **GOOGLE API**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer which gives me actual distance.

```
- (NSArray*)getRoutePointFrom:(myannotation *)origin to:(myannotation *)destination 
{
    NSString* sourcePoint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",origin.coordinate.latitude, origin.coordinate.longitude];
    NSString* destinationPoint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", destination.coordinate.latitude, destination.coordinate.longitude];

    NSString* apiUrlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=%@&daddr=%@", sourcePoint, destinationPoint];
    NSURL* apiUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:apiUrlStr];

    NSError *error;//saddr
    NSString *apiResponse = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:apiUrl encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"points:\"([^\"]*)\"" options:0 error:NULL];
    NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:apiResponse options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [apiResponse length])];
    NSString *encodedPoints = [apiResponse substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];

    NSRegularExpression *distRegEx=[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"tooltipHtml:\"([^\"]*)\""options:0 error:NULL];
    NSTextCheckingResult *distmatch=[tempregx firstMatchInString:apiResponse options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [apiResponse length])];

    NSString *dist= [apiResponse substringWithRange:[temppmatch rangeAtIndex:0]];
    NSLog(@"dist in Km: %@",dist);
    return [self decodePolyLine:[encodedPoints mutableCopy]];
  }
```

Comment: This uses Google api! The question was to not use Google Api.

Comment: Since there is no other option for me. Hence this is last solution for me.

Comment: Strictly speaking you're not allowed to display data from Google on non-Google Maps, it's in their license agreement, but I don't know how enforced that is.

Comment: hi mahi, what is the temppmatch object? in this code.

Answer (score 2):

If you're ok with only using iOS 7, get an `MKRoute` from the [`MKDirections`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKDirections_class/Reference/Reference.html) API. The route has a `distance` property which is the travel distance (i.e. not as the crow flies).

Comment: No. I am using iOS6. So I am searching according to that

Answer (score 0):

You `can't find the distance based on roads with the Apple SDK`. If you really want ,then you must go through directly to google APIs.:

> http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/maps/index.html

Comment: kk.. But I don't Know How to use that.

Comment: You need to import the Google MAp SDk .Please Go through this Doc : **https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/?hl=fr-FR** and samples over ther